# Error Executing SparkSubmitOperator from Airflow Job

Tags: linux, apache-spark, airflow, apache-spark-sql

Background : I have created a new Airflow Job/Task DAG in which I am using the SparkSubmitOperator. I am running both Spark and Airflow on my desktop (Versions etc. below). The DAG works fine until it reaches the Submit portion for the Spark job. I've tried to change the connection using the below options. Regardless what I attempt, I receive the below message in the Airflow log.

Airflow recognizes the connection and attempts to use it but fails.

If I submit the target DataPipelineExample.py from the command prompt, it run without issue.

**Question: What is stopping Airflow from recognizing and using the connection to spark local for executing spark-submit?**

Airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: Cannot execute: spark-submit --master http://localhost:4040 --name mySparkSubmitJob

Desktop : Linux Mint VERSION="19.3 (Tricia)"
Spark : version 2.4.5
Pyspark : version 2.4.5
Airflow : Version : 1.10.9
Python 3.7.4 (default, Aug 13 2019, 20:35:49) 
java version "1.8.0_241"

Airflow Connections Used or Tried
localhost 4040
spark://localhost 4040
http://localhost:4040
http://specific ip address:4040
Host: localhost Port: 4040 / Extras, No Extras etc.
Extras : { "root.default",: "spark_home": "", "spark_binary": "spark-submit", "namespace": "default"}

Path Information

```
export SCALA_HOME=~/anaconda3/share/scala-2.11.1
export SPARK_HOME=/usr/local/spark
export PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS="--master local[2] pyspark-shell"
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/spark/bin
```

Below the full DAG. This compiles and is fully recognized by Python and Airflow.

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator
from airflow.contrib.operators.spark_submit_operator import SparkSubmitOperator
from airflow.models import Variable
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

default_args = {
    'owner': 'me@gmail.com',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': datetime(2020, 3, 17),
    'email': ['me@gmail.com'],
    'email_on_failure': True,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5),
    # 'queue': 'bash_queue',
    # 'pool': 'backfill',
    # 'priority_weight': 10,
    'end_date': datetime(2030, 3, 17),
}

dag = DAG(dag_id = 'a_data_pipelne_job', default_args=default_args, schedule_interval='*/45 * * * *')

t1 = BashOperator(
    task_id='print_date',
    bash_command='date',
    dag=dag)

print_path_env_task = BashOperator(
    task_id='print_path_env',
    bash_command='echo $PATH',
    dag=dag)

spark_submit_task = SparkSubmitOperator(
    task_id='spark_submit_job_02',
    conn_id='spark_local',
    application = "/home/me/.config/spyder-py3/DataPipelineExample.py",
    name='airflowspark-DataLoaderMongo',
    verbose=True,
    dag=dag,
)

t1.set_upstream(print_path_env_task)
spark_submit_task.set_upstream(t1)
```

Comment: Can you share what your `spark_local` connection looks like? If I see it correctly, the error message says `No Extras` maybe you need to define the `Extras`

Answer (score 1):

I was able to work around this issue by using the SSHOperator. It is less vulnerable to environmental configuration issues than the SparkSubmitOperator. SparkSubmit is called via SSH in the context of the local pyspark home. Add the path argument for your python script and you're good to go.

```
dag = DAG(dag_id = 'a_pjm_data_pipelne__ssh_job', 
                  default_args=default_args, 
                  schedule_interval='*/60 * * * *',
                  params={'project_source': '/home/me/.config/spyder-py3',
                  'spark_submit': '/usr/local/spark/bin/spark-submit DataPipelineExample.py'})

templated_bash_command = """
    echo 'HOSTNAME: localhost' #To check that you are properly connected to the host
    cd {{ params.project_source }}
    {{ params.spark_submit }}
"""

t1 = BashOperator(
    task_id='print_date',
    bash_command='date',
    dag=dag)

print_path_env_task = BashOperator(
    task_id='print_path_env',
    bash_command='echo $PATH',
    dag=dag)

submit_spark_task = SSHOperator(
    task_id="SSH_task",
    ssh_conn_id='ssh_default',
    command=templated_bash_command,
    dag=dag
```